# Suppose |+|=||=||. Determine the angle  between  and .

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I solved through the equation and got u=0, v=0, but then the angle would be undefined. Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: Hint: $|u+v|^2 =(u+v)\cdot(u+v) = |u|^2+|v|^2+2|u||v|\cos \theta$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within given conditions, this is the corresponding vector polygon.

[image: img]

Angle between two vectors is defined as the angle between them when both vectors are pointing towards the same point. Thus, the angle between $\mathbb u$ and $\mathbb v$ is $$\theta=120^\circ$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that $|u|^2 = u \cdot u$,

$$|u+v|^2 =(u+v)\cdot(u+v) = |u|^2+|v|^2+2|u||v|\cos \theta$$

Since $|u+v|=|u|=|v|$ we can plug it in everywhere,

$$|u|^2 = |u|^2+|u|^2+2|u|^2\cos \theta$$

Now divide it out and rearrange a bit,

$$-\frac{1}{2} = \cos \theta$$

In other words, $\theta = \arccos(\frac{-1}{2}) = \frac{2\pi}{3}$.

For example, you can use the vectors $u=(1,0)$ and $v=(-1/2, \sqrt{3}/2)$

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically, the three vectors form a triangle, and since all three vectors have the same magnitude, the triangle must be equilateral. Thus the angle between $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ must be the external angle to an equilateral triangle, i.e. $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Comment: Yes, of course, I really should proof-read before posting!

Comment: I would say the angle must be be $2\pi/3$. Be aware $|1+\exp(i\frac{2\pi}{3})|=1$, but not $|1+\exp(i\frac{\pi}{3})|$

Comment: This answer is wrong, the angle is interpreted based on placing the vectors incorrectly on the triangle.

Comment: Not at all, and thanks for pointing out the error; have made a correction.